# How to re-activate the Drupal administrator account that got accidently blocked?

Tags: users

The admin user account of my Drupal site accidently got deactivated. Because of that, I have no more access to Drupal administration.

How can I change the status of that user account to active again?

Comment: What do you mean by "deactivated"?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more info? Have you tried the reset password link on /user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the *users* table and in the admin row, check the *status* column. 0 means blocked and 1 means active. Make sure it is set to 1.

Comment: salam. I did it now but the password has been changed before deactivation of the account. I sent myself an email and now everything is OK. I just got panic for some mins! haha

Comment: Very well compatriot ;)

Answer (score 2):

hope you have an access to the db.

goto table users->edit for your admin profile->change status from 0 to 1->now your admin acc is activ.

Comment: How your answer is different from  [Druapalist's Answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/157571/25879) ? :)

Comment: It's the same answer, just he was a bit faster with his ^^